# SQLite, how to find in all?

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQL newbie here, just learning how to do some basics. Working in SQLite, If I have an array of conditions I can search for any matches using `IN`, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE job_id IN (1,2,3)
```

In this contrived example, this would give me any people with job id 1, 2 or 3. However, in a different case, how could I make this an ALL condition? Ie. select people with `job_id` matching all terms in the array?

I think that in some dbs you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE job_id IN ALL (1,2,3)
```

But when I try this in SQLite I get `syntax error near ALL`. So, how do you do this in SQLite, and, for bonus points, is there a way to write this kind of query that would also be compatible with PostgreSQL?

Comment: How can you match three job IDs when the `job_id` column can store only one value? Can you show an example table?

Comment: CL: I appologize, I gave kind of a contrived example. I'm looking to use this in several places, but the one I'm having the most trouble with is a many-to-many join where I'll be searching the join table for matches. Your comment helps me understand why my approach wouldn't work, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT columName          -- fetch only single column
FROM people 
WHERE job_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

behind the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` is to count all the number of records match by the `job_id`

Comment: @Mark nope, you can still use `DISTINCT`, eg `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) = 3`